# Dell "identify server" light in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, dell, rackmount

Does anyone know of a way to turn on the identification light on a Dell rack-mount server. This is the light which you can switch on locally by pushing the (i) button on the front of the server which turns on lights in the front and rear of the server?

The machine is a Dell Poweredge 860.

I'm trying to identify a server in Utah from AZ. Haven't had much experience with it, so forgive me if this is a newb question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like [ipmitool](http://ipmitool.sourceforge.net/) is [available](http://www.freebsdsoftware.org/sysutils/ipmitool.html) for FreeBSD.  Running `ipmitool chassis identify` should trigger the ID light for 15 seconds.  If you're running it locally on the box, I believe the full command will be `ipmitool -I open chassis identify`.

From `man ipmitool`:

```
identify <interval>

   Control the front panel identify  light.   Default is 15.
   Use 0 to turn off.
```

**EDIT:**
Further research indicates you probably don't want the `-I open` option an that you first need to run `kldload ipmi` to load the kernel module.